# Java wait for method to return object

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, user-interface

I am making a library where an application can use it to capture a selection of a screen and convert it to an image, like Gyazo.

This library is not the application itself, but only the tool that returns the File or BufferedImage object to the application.

I want the application to be simple as this:

```
Bootstrap b = new Boostrap(new GifCapturer());
b.beginCapture(); // user selects an area
File file = b.getFile();
```

But how can I make the application wait till the library returns the object? as you see the `beginCapture` method should activate the JFrame where the user will select an area to capture.

Do I need to sleep the thread? or use listeners design?

The beginCapture method starts a jframe window, where the user is able to select an area of the screen. Once selected, the library will convert the selected area to an object and set it as a local variable. So when you will use getFile it ill return the captured image. But the thing is, i need to make sure that the image was selected before getFile call gets executed, and wait instead but im not sure how.

Sorry if the question is not detailed, im on phone.
Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a listener, that is invoked as soon the selection is ready. Put your `File file = b.getFile();` code into the listener.

The code of your JFrame would be necessary to give a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to use a Listener with a own built listener class, and interface.
Create an interface which you will use to get the data, or that will get know when the listener gets called, like this in my case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
    Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap(new GifCapturer());
    b.beginCapture(new ScreenCaptureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void captureEnded(File file) {
            System.out.println("done!");
        }
    });
}
```